# How do I develop a registration form leveraging MVC principles?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am new to the world of coding and am having a hard time understanding what MVC is and how I can apply it to PHP. At the risk of this question being closed I have scoured the web for numerous articles however none of them explain them explain MVC in a way I can understand.

For example, I came across the article at Coding Horror - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html however I am unsure how I can apply it to PHP. I apologise for posting an ambiguous question earlier however I hope this question is more direct.

Let's take a look at example that will hopefully help me understand. The objective is a user must complete a registration form that will have the details recorded in a database.

I currently have the following files
 - a PHP file (i.e. with the extension PHP) with XHTML markup - There is no code in here as yet except XHTML mark-up
 - a CSS file

I have also have a MySQL database

1. How would develop the registration form using MVC?
2. What files should I have?
3. What folder structures would I have?

I am not looking for actual code but an example of how I would develop a MVC application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folder structures are irrelevant. The main point of MVC is a **logical** separation.

You should have one *model*, which takes care of your data. This includes storing data in the database (or elsewhere), validating the integrity of data (i.e. make sure all values are as you want them, no strings in fields where you want numbers etc.) and retrieving data.

You should have a *view*, which just presents data to the user or gives the user an interface to interact with your application. That's typically your files containing (X)HTML.

Then you need a *controller* that makes these two things work together. The controller is responsible for receiving user requests, deciding what to do with them and *rendering* an appropriate view in response.

These three parts can be realized in many ways (classes, objects, functions, files), as long as the *logical separation* is preserved. The logical separation makes things easier in the long run, since you always keep the core of the application (models) separate from the presentation (views) and can dynamically combine both in many ways (using controllers).

The typical logical flow for a form would be:

- controller renders a view containing a form
- form is submitted to controller
- the controller tries to save the data using the model
- the model validates the data, gives thumbs down if it is invalid or thumbs up if it was saved correctly
- if thumbs down, the controller outputs an error message
- if thumbs up, the controller redirect the user along to the next step

Visualized it's something like this:

```
Request --> Controller --> View --> Response
              |   ^
              v   |
              Model
              |   ^
              v   |
             Database
```

I suggest you start playing around with an existing MVC framework to get the feel for it.

Comment: @deceze - Thanks. Please correct me if I am wrong. 


Model - This is a single PHP file that would make the database connection,
validate the data being entered in the form e.g. invalid email address, 
incorrect name length, etc, insert into the database the values of the form,
etc. Following OOP principles, each one of these would be or could be
separate classes

View - This is a bunch of files that render the look and feel of the form e.g.
XHTML and CSS

Comment: @deceze - Controller - Forgive me for being naive here, why have the controller when all it is doing is passing information typed out in the form to the file that does database connections. the validation, insertion, etc. 

Can you give me an example of what request a controller would handle?

Comment: @Peanuts The model(s) is *typically* one class per database table. I.e. the model `class User` would take care of the table `users`, `class Car` would take care of `cars` etc. Also, don't think of the model as validating *forms*, models validate **data** that may come from anywhere. The controller supplies data to the model (from whatever source) and decides in which form to respond to the user. Think of implementing a JSON-powered API as alternative/addition to forms, and you see where MVC becomes useful.

Comment: @Peanuts When the data "enters" your application, it stops being a *form* and should be converted to a consistent internal representation of data. This may just be a standardized array format or a data object. This object can be passed around between the controller, model and view and it doesn't matter how it got there. Only the view renders it as a concrete representation like HTML, JSON or XML. That's **abstraction**, and it really helps as your app grows and becomes more complex.

Comment: @deceze - Thanks. I understood each table having its own class however was lost what you meant by **data from anywhere**. As an example how would this relate to say my example form? Assuming it is a standard XHTML form how would the controller supply the data?

Comment: @deceze - I am sorry for being a complete noob bit what do you mean by internal representation of data and passing the object around?

Comment: @Peanuts Imagine the case of an API. A client sends JSON or XML data to you. That's not a form, yet you still want to handle it with the same models (because you don't want to redo your validation and database logic). So you first decode the JSON or XML into an array (your internal representation), *then* you give it to the model. Who should do this work of decoding? It's not the model's responsibility and it's certainly not the view's (views only *output* data). It's the controller doing it. And the controller will also decide to render an alternative JSON/XML view instead of a webpage.

Comment: @deceze - Ah right. Think it is starting to make sense although am confused by the term `decoding`?

Comment: @Peanuts Pardon my French, *parsing* would have been more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @deceze - That's cool. No biggie. So again just to make sure I have understood the concept. The model view would make say the database connections, validate the data, execute the responses, etc. It then passes on these details on the controller which then passes this onto the view which presents the users with any errors that may have occurred or simply the message displaying thank you. Now assuming the when the user visits the website or say information is passed to the controller and there is a issue with connecting with the database e.g. the model returns an error saying

Comment: @deceze - problem with database, this would then be passed back to the controller which then passes it back to the view.

Comment: @Peanuts The flow is: controller receives request, controller decides which models need to be involved, controller uses models as needed, models take care of their domain (database interaction, data validation) and tell the controller about any problems, controller decides how to respond to the user (error messages? normal view? redirect? HTML, XML, JSON?), controller passes data for output to view, view renders the given data in appropriate format. See my awesome ASCII visualization above.

Comment: @deceze - Thanks so much that makes so much more sense now. The question I do have about the controller is if I am developing a registration form and develop a controller to handle all the requests, do I have to develop it to manage all types of request e.g. HTML, XML, JSON, etc or simply to develop it for the specific requirement at that moment e.g. HTML.

Comment: @Peanuts Just develop what you're actually going to use. Try not to paint yourself too much into a corner though, in case you do decide to add some alternative method later. As I said, playing around with existing frameworks is probably best for developing the right feeling.

Comment: @deceze - Thanks. The only concern I have playing around with existing frameworks is that I won't fully grasp the concept of separating logic from presentation as I have never coded before. I'll certainly give it a go through. Really appreciate all the help you have given. I take it that frameworks such as CodeIgnter and FuelPHP are a good starting ground for a newbie.

Comment: @Peanuts CakePHP takes its MVC architecture very serious and may be good for that reason. Fuel and CI are fine too.

Comment: @deceze - Thanks. You have been of great help.